# Python 3.3: Sorting a List of Objects/Methods

Tags: python, list, class, methods

I apologize I am not sure of the terminology of Python.

I have a Class called "Word" and what it does is count and store all the words in a given text file as a tuple I.e.

```
self.listName = [('world', 2), ('hello', 3), ('stack', 1), ('overflow', 2)]
```

where the item of index 0 is the word and index 1 is the occurrences.  This is stored within the the class "word".  is there any way I can use the

```
listName.sort()
```

or

```
sorted(listName, key=lambda Word: Word[0])
```

to give me the following list:

```
self.listName = [('hello', 3), ('overflow', 2), ('stack', 1), ('world', 2)]
```

I want to try to use this rather than attempting to create a new sorting function (which I believe I can do, but I have not been successful)?

I think I should also mention that the List and the Word classes are in different classes (if that makes a difference).

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really able to visualize what your class structure looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort your list,

```
listname.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
```

should sort the list in place alphabetically by word.

Also, you may want to look up

```
collections.counter
```

as it serves a similar purpose to what you are doing

Comment: I will look it up, but it was how I was sorting the information within my word class

Comment: Re: Collections.counter

I am actually supposed to compare the hashtable method and a list method for doing this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the `key` at all,

```
listName = [('world', 2), ('hello', 3), ('stack', 1), ('overflow', 2)]
print(sorted(listName))
```

**Output**

```
[('hello', 3), ('overflow', 2), ('stack', 1), ('world', 2)]
```

For more information about how this comparison is done, please check this documentation page [Comparing Sequences and Other Types](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work, I needed a "over rider method" (? - where I need to define __lt__ to compare the str element of Word()) though because I got this error:
     TypeError: unorderable types: str() < Word()